# How do I filter elements in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Sample Array:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,2,2,2]
```

Filter:

```
y = [2,4,7,9]
```

Desired output:

```
result = [2,4,2,2,2]
```

I tried:

```
result = (x & y)
```

but this gives me `[4,2]`.

How do I get: `result = [2,4,2,2,2]`?

Comment: What about the first 2 in `x`?

Comment: He fixed it, looked like a typo.  Also, what's with the close vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
x - (x - y)
#=> [2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

1-2 lines longer than @Mark's answer, but more efficient (if both arrays are large):

```
require 'set'
keep   = Set[2,4,7,9] # or Set.new(some_large_array)
result = x.select{ |n| keep.include?(n) } #=> [2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

*The problem with writing...*

```
x.select{ |i| y.include?(i) }
```

*...is that this is O(x*y) the the number of elements in each array. With 100 elements in each you are doing 10,000 operations in the worst case; my answer does only 100 operations.*

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil!  But yeah, turning `y` into a Set could help performance.  Also, I think the sorting of the result in the example is coincidental; it's got the elements in the same order as they were in the input list.

Comment: Also: IMHO understanding algorithmic complexity and picking one that is not potentially disastrous is not the same as premature optimization. It's just good coding. In the large software company that I work for you would be surprised by how many O(n^3) algorithms we've found buried in the code, placed there by interns years prior. These pieces of code eventually caused completely unacceptable  performance problems when the product was used on slightly larger data sets.

Comment: Well, I've seen more production issues caused by overcomplexity (some of it introduced by yours truly) than poor algorithm choices. In this case, even for small lists, there's probably no downside to using the Set, but in some analogous cases the overhead of the setup required to make the more efficient algorithm possible can easily trump the gains. That's why it's important to understand your data domain and transaction volume and that's where the "premature" part comes in. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, don't capitalize variables in Ruby.  Capitalization is for constants, like class names.

```
result = x.select {|i| y.include? i}
```

Note that `select` is also called `find_all`, and is the positive filter in ruby; the negative filter is `reject`.  Between the braces you can put any code you want; it will be run once for each item of `x` (the item is passed in as an argument and becomes `i`), and the result of the whole call will include all the elements for which the block returns a true value.